# Scaling beyond 65k open files (TCP connections)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, filesystems

I have a requirement for my Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS server to have >65k clients connected to it via TCP. Although I have memory & cpu to spare I'm unable to get more than 65k clients to connect. I suspected it's an open file limit issue, however I have followed the many existing solutions on stackoverflow to change the limit on the number of open files but I'm still hitting the limit. I made the following changes..

**/etc/security/limits.conf**

```
*    soft nofile 500000
*    hard nofile 500000
root soft nofile 500000
root hard nofile 500000
```

**/etc/pam.d/common-session**

```
session required pam_limits.so
```

**/etc/pam.d/common-session-noninteractive**

```
session required pam_limits.so
```

**/etc/sysctl.conf**

```
fs.file-max = 500000
```

When I check ulimit it looks to be correctly updated, as you can see below...

```
:~$ ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 30038
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 500000
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 30038
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited

:~$ cat /proc/1739/limits
Limit                     Soft Limit           Hard Limit           Units
Max cpu time              unlimited            unlimited            seconds
Max file size             unlimited            unlimited            bytes    
Max data size             unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Max stack size            unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Max core file size        0                    unlimited            bytes
Max resident set          unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Max processes             30038                30038                processes
Max open files            500000               500000               files
Max locked memory         65536                65536                bytes
Max address space         unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Max file locks            unlimited            unlimited            locks
Max pending signals       30038                30038                signals
Max msgqueue size         819200               819200               bytes
Max nice priority         0                    0
Max realtime priority     0                    0
Max realtime timeout      unlimited            unlimited            us
```

Unfortunately there still seems to be some limit somewhere preventing additional clients being added as the server hits 65,589 open files and refuses to open additional files (tcp connections).

```
:~$ sudo ls /proc/1739/fd | wc -l
65589
```

Is there some other setting in ubuntu / linux that needs to be changed?

**Update**

`vm.max_map_count` seems to have done the trick by setting  `sudo sysctl vm.max_map_count=16777216` and adding the vm.map_map_count entry to `/etc/sysctl.conf`.

As you can see...

```
:~$ sudo ls /proc/2391/fd | wc -l
73609
:~$ netstat -an | grep ESTABLISHED | wc -l
73561
```

I'll have to be careful of course to set the number of open files to a limit that corresponds to the desired amount of memory utilization. Off the link @sysadmin1138 provided there was another page recommending a rough guide of 16K of memory per map (open tcp socket), which seems like a good place to start.  Although I am seeing a different symptom now, where the number of open files / sockets fluctuates when the server attempts to publish a message to the connected clients. So that will require some further investigation.

Comment: What is the error that you received?

Comment: Have you considered scaling horizontally?  This seems fairly excessive for vertical scaling.

Comment: @FalconMomot normally I'd agree with you, however this is a publish & subscriber architecture where the server is the publisher and clients the subscribers. The subscribers have a very low impact once connected to the server, so we'd be left with each small server only utilising 10% cpu and 15% memory. If we start supporting millions of clients then it's highly inefficient to waste 80% of each server's capacity due to some mystery limit.

Comment: great question, we have a very similar setup as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [Max number of socket on Linux](https://serverfault.com/questions/168285/max-number-of-socket-on-linux), the sysctl variable `vm.max_map_count` may be of use here.

Comment: `vm.max_map_count` seems to have done the trick..

Comment: I had thought that @BrandonXavier's answer would be correct.  Are these connections spread over multiple interfaces?  (maybe virtual ones, but separate IPs)

Answer (score 3):

You may be bumping into the limitation of 16 bit ports (65536).

Comment: Not if his machine is the server and they are all connecting to the same port, AFAIU.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by others your probably hitting the maximum number of ports allowed on a single interface.

You could probably add an interface alice bind your app on that IP and start servicing requests from the new IP.