# apache performance benchmarking using ab command

Tags: apache-2.2

benchinmarking using ab command gave following error message how to fix it?

**apr_poll: The timeout specified has expired (70007)**

Answer (score 0):

Fix your Apache or network configuration, ab is unable to connect your Apache.

Answer (score 0):

What switches are you currently using?
It might be 
 1. Network issue
 2. Your webserver taking too long to respond
 3. Maximum number of connections reached

[Relevant](https://serverfault.com/questions/10852/what-limits-the-maximum-number-of-connections-on-a-linux-server)